# What's meaning of "the leading edge of edgy"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read a sentence that made me confused when I studied a new word: 'edge'.

> The brand new W hotel Paris-Opera is on the **leading edge of edgy** in
> Paris.

*Article: http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20120907-business-trip-paris*

---

What I am confused is a phrase: 'leading edge of edgy'?

'leading edge' means advantage, 'edgy' may means cutting-edge there.

> I think cutting-edge include advantage meaning, so, is 'leading edge'
> unnecessary?
>
> And, the word follows 'of' should be a noun., right? But 'edgy' is a adj.?!

Comment: This is a model ELL question, and I hope it attracts the high number of upvotes it deserves. It gives the full sentence of where the sentence was found (including a link to the original article), and also mentions that the OP was studying the word _edge_. It explicitly states assumptions and the fruits of prior research, making it easier for the community to pinpoint areas of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see where you might have got the idea that “leading” means “advantage”, but that’s not the case here. In this case, “leading edge” is an idiom that means “advanced.” I found a good explanation of this idiom at [this website](http://www.word-detective.com/2011/12/cutting-edge-leading-edge/):

> “Cutting-edge” and “leading-edge” are both adjectives used (especially in product promotional materials and corporate “mission statements”) to mean “**At the forefront or most advanced stage of development; highly innovative or pioneering**.” Both are also used as nouns (without the hyphens) to mean that highly-advanced state of awesomeness (“Professors, commonly assumed to be on the leading edge of thought…” Fortune, 1983). “Cutting-edge” and “leading-edge” are most often used in the context of technology (computers, cell phones, flying cars, etc.), and only rarely do we read of “cutting edge quilts” or “leading-edge pot roast recipes.”

In your sentence, the writer is employing some wordplay there. A researcher may be on *the leading edge of science*, and professor David Roitstein wants the CalArts program to stay on the *[leading edge of music technology](https://jazztimes.com/departments/education/current-trends-in-jazz-education/)*, but this hotel is on *the leading edge of edgy*. Taken literally, that seems like a redundant expression: We can have a *leading-edge hotel*, or we can have an *edgy hotel* – why say both? But I think the author is onto something; it’s a “punny” way to say that the hotel is ultra-edgy, or on the "extreme edge of edginess." Given that Paris is such as trendy location, I’m assuming this is intended to be quite high praise for the hotel being reviewed.

---

As for why it’s acceptable to use an adjective as the object, that’s an astute observation that I think many native speakers would have missed.

I looked up the expression “at the leading edge of innovative” online; I found many hits, but the word *innovative* was always modifying a trailing noun (as in, “at the leading edge of innovative design”). So the rules of grammar are indeed being bent here, but it’s a good example to demonstrate the flexibility of English.

Because of the deliberate wordplay, I think *edgy* can function informally as a grammatical noun in your sentence – even though it’s normally used as an adjective. The phrase “at the leading edge of edginess” might seem like a more grammatical way to say it, but the problem with that is we associate the word *edginess* with *nervousness*, while the word *edgy* is more closely associated with *trendy*.